# Nginx sending traffic to wrong port

Tags: nginx

I have the 2 Nginx config files (the domains are changed for privacy).

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name beta.mydomain.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name mydomain.io, www.mydomain.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3002;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

For some reason navigating to mydomain.io takes you to the beta one, only www.mydomain.io takes you to the one on port 3002. I can't seem to find anyone else running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to post this question then realised my mistake. I included a comma in between the domains which isn't correct syntax for the server_name directive. I hope it helps someone else. I removed it and restarted the nginx server. It's working perfectly now.